# REACT Props is undefined in useLayoutEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my parent component I pass prop `mainPostion` to the cursor component but the problem is the prop inside the `useLayoutEffect` hook is undefined and outside the `useLayoutEffect` is defined.

```js
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { StyledCursor } from "../../setup/styled_components/styled_component";

const Cursor = ({ darkModeButtonPosition, mainPostion }) => {
  console.log("mainPostion: ", mainPostion); //defined
  const cursorRef = useRef(null);
  const onMouseMove = (event) => {
    const { clientX, clientY } = event;
    cursorRef.current.style.left = `${clientX - 15}px`;
    cursorRef.current.style.top = `${clientY - 15}px`;
    console.log("mainPostion: ", mainPostion); // defined
  };

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // FIXME? why mainPostion here is undefind and outside is defined
    console.log("mainPostion: ", mainPostion);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <StyledCursor
      ref={cursorRef}
      animate={{ scale: [1, 0.8, 1] }}
      transition={{
        duration: 2,
        loop: Infinity,
        type: "tween",
      }}
    ></StyledCursor>
  );
};

export default Cursor;
```

Comment: ***Other than*** for logging what purposes does this `mainPostion` prop serve? It's not referenced by anything so it's unclear what any real issue is. The event listeners should be added in a `useEffect` hook, there's no point really in using the `useLayoutEffect`. Where is this `mainPostion` prop value declared? You mention a parent component but then neglect to include it as part of a complete and relevant [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

#### It's because useLayoutEffect executes right after all DOM mutations

So the first time that the component renders (as there are no DOM mutations) all the outside context variables are not yet defined.

[see reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect).

If you use useEffect instead you won't have this problem. For what i can see in your code you don't need to run that code right after DOM mutations.

So changing it to use a useEffect should be straight up.

Comment: thank u so much for your answer 
i found a solution to this its by adding the props to the array dependency of useLyoutEffect

Comment: That's good but keep in mind that useLayoutEffect may not be the use case here.